# Replace Plumbing Stubs for Renovation?

Tags: plumbing

I'm renovating a 3,500 sq. ft office space with 12 various water "stubs" (toilets & sink hot and cold supplies).

I had a recent divorce with my long time plumber, who usually would come in, replace the copper stubs from the walls and re-do the shutoffs and escutcheons, and then come in in hook up all the finish pieces after we paint.  (So basically the point is that the stubs look brand new and fancy).

The stubs are about 20 years old and the copper is bit aged and old looking.   Do you need to replace the stubs?  Is there a common practice here for that?

I want to replace the shutsoffs and escutcheons since everything will be open and easy to do, but the stubs?

Comment: `divorce` why, get him back

Comment: Come back in another 80 or 100 years about replacing.  20 year old copper just need cleaning/sanding if soldering on new fixtures/pieces.  Think most of the new push on/compression fittings can just be put on.

Comment: The divorce is personality / professionalism related.  Guy does good work when he isn't high and/or crabby -- just hard to deal with in the mix of all the other trades coming in.

Answer (score 1):

20 year old copper is still a baby.  No need to replace the stubs unless there is some physical damage that makes the pipe unusable.

Comment: Thanks,  that clears my head